# JShell How to find the type of Variable or Result

Tags: java, jshell

How to find the type of a variable or Expression Result in JShell.

Was experimenting Bitwise Operators in Java

```
jshell> byte b=5<<-1;
|  Error:
|  incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
|  byte b=5<<-1;
|         ^---^

jshell> 5<<-1
$2 ==> -2147483648

jshell>
```

Is there an alternative like Python type(5<<-1) to find the result type of expression or variable in Jshell.

Comment: The error message is saying that the output of the bitwise operation is an `int` and not a `byte`.

Comment: True, I realized the type mismatch. Bit operations involve promotion to int.
Would be even more handy to find without Error or Exception, Sometimes there may not be one.

Comment: In [java repl](http://www.javarepl.com/term.html) use the `:type` command, e.g. `:type 5<<-1`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just figured out it can be solved by setting the feedback mode.

```
/set feedback verbose
```

Reference https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/feedback-modes.htm

Now can easily find the type of an expression or variable in the response.

```
jshell> 5<<-1
$15 ==> -2147483648
|  created scratch variable $15 : int
```

The mode can be reset by using the command

```
/set feedback normal
```

and the current mode can be queried by simply calling

```
/set feedback
```

Comment: And, could change it back via: `/set feedback normal` .

Comment: @EricWang Updated the answer now.

Comment: Also, if you want to check the current setting, just use `/set feedback`, it will print the current setting.

Comment: @EricWang Thanks Updated.

Answer (score 4):

I found an explicit way to do this (I'm running with JDK11)
using the /vars command

```
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> 5<<-1
$1 ==> -2147483648

jshell> /vars
|    int $1 = -2147483648
```