# JShell error "unexpected type" when using specific class name

Tags: java, jshell

I was just playing around with JShell, and it seems that defining `class Z{}` and then defining
`var z = new Z()` does not work. But using different class names, like `class X` and `class A`, does work.

Surely I must be missing something obvious...?

```
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 14.0.1
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> class X{}
|  created class X

jshell> class Z{}
|  created class Z

jshell> var x = new X()
x ==> X@26a1ab54
|  created variable x : X

jshell> var z = new Z()
|  Error:
|  unexpected type
|    required: class
|    found:    type parameter Z
|  var z = new Z();
|              ^

jshell> class A{}
|  created class A

jshell> var a = new A()
a ==> A@2ef1e4fa
|  created variable a : A
```

Comment: What's weird is `Z z = new Z()` seems to work just fine.

Comment: Let me take a guess... JShell uses `Z` internally as type name.

Comment: even `new Z();` without variable assignment works fine: `jshell> new Z();
$8 ==> Z@6e5e91e4`

Comment: Looks like it -- [`jdk.jshell`'s `Wrap.java` includes `Z` as a type parameter](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/jdk.jshell/share/classes/jdk/jshell/Wrap.java#l113).

Comment: I think this should be reported as bug, and the type parameter renamed to something like `$JShell$Z`.

Comment: Bug [JDK-8257236](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8257236), fixed in JDK 17.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use of `var` can lead to a variable having a [non-denotable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630871/java-10-var-and-capture-variable). For example, [looking at the return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629237/jshell-how-to-find-the-type-of-variable-or-result) of an expression that could be `String` or `Integer`:

```
jshell> /set feedback verbose
jshell> var x = true ? "a" : 1
x ==> "a"
|  created variable x : Serializable&Comparable<? extends Serializable&Comparable<?>&java.lang.constant.Constable&java.lang.constant.ConstantDesc>&java.lang.constant.Constable&java.lang.constant.ConstantDesc
```

When `jshell` is evaluating your code fragment, if this is the case, it [wraps it in a block of code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/jdk.jshell/share/classes/jdk/jshell/Wrap.java#l113) so that it can record this type for later use. The wrapping fragment includes a generic type parameter called `Z`:

```
        // private static <Z> Z do_itAux() {
        //     wtype x_ = y;
        //     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        //     Z x__ = (Z) x_;
        //     return x__;
```

This parameter's name leaks into the code block being evaluated, meaning the class's name is shadowed by the type parameter. This makes `Z` a special case -- the other single character examples are fine.

Comment: oh darn! `/set feedback verbose` this is something I wish was present in `javac` output for non-denotable types, thx so much!